# Save array to BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I've just started on BigQuery, and I wonder whether I can work with arrays natively or should I use a json string instead. Array data type is not listed on big query as a supported type. I need to save an array (list) of users objects to BigQuery.

What's the currently best approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Array data type is not listed on big query as a supported type.

Yes, it is a supported data type. From [the data types documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array-type):

> An ARRAY is an ordered list of zero or more elements of non-ARRAY values.

Comment: Why I cannot see a type array at the form for creating a table?

Comment: The current UI uses BigQuery "legacy SQL" concepts for types, so you have to pick "REPEATED" as the mode for the column to create an array. If you want to specify an `ARRAY` type directly, use a [`CREATE TABLE` statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language#create_table_statement).

Answer (score -1):

Array data type is not listed on big query as a supported type.

But, use RECORD data type.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP question. Nested and Repeated are two different types and Record uses Nested vs Repeated.